# How to get the total folder size node_modules recursively on specified path?

Tags: bash, recursion, node-modules

I want to know how much space this `node_modules` folder take in my machine.

What command line i can use to get total size of this `node_modules` recursively inside specified path?

Comment: What's wrong with `du`?

Comment: `du -ch node_modules | grep total`

Comment: @zzxyz its only get total size node_modules in one folder

Comment: @DedeHamzah I'm not sure I understand.  You have a folder with multiple node_modules in it?  `find folder_path -name 'node_modules' -print0 | xargs -0 du -ch`

Comment: The above may not work if the number of node_modules is very high.  Add `| grep total` to the end to make sure you only get one result.

Comment: `find folder_path -name 'node_modules' -print0 | xargs -r -0 du -c | grep total | awk 'BEGIN{newVar=0;}{newVar += strtonum($1);}END{print newVar/1000  "M"}'`  No idea whether that's what you're asking, but I'm learning awk, so...

Comment: `find . -name 'node_modules' -print0 | xargs -r -0 du -c | awk '/total/{newVar += strtonum($1);}END{print newVar/1000  "M"}'` <--useless use of grep and unneeded init removed.